# How to display a custom title of a multi-select choice column in sharepoint with JSON?

Tags: json, sharepoint

I have acronyms in a multi-choice column in SharePoint. 
I want to display the title that describes the acronym.  For example, when I mouse over ATZ, maybe I want it to say "At The Zoo - ATZ".
I'm just learning to use this and can't seem to find a way to assign a string for each $ChoiceIterator in the loop. I can put the $ChoiceIterator in the title, but I want to add a unique description for each title.

Thanks!

I've tried samples from this site https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/column-samples/multi-choice-icons

Using this snip after the "title": and trying to insert my $ChoiceIterator appropriately.

```
"=if(indexOf(join(@currentField,''),'dog') != -1, 'Yes', 'No')
```

But the results are simply that it shows the same text for every icon selection.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "choiceIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[$choiceIterator]",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-white",
        "title": "='This should describe the license... ' + [$choiceIterator]"
      },
      "style": {
        "width": "27px",
        "height": "16px",
        "text-align": "center",
        "margin": "2px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the above answer works, but it displays all the icons all the time.  In my in my case, I didn't want Icons, I wanted to be able to create and select custom acronyms on my multi-choice column.

To make the example simple:
I have a list of customers in rows.  One column is multi-choice of the custom features of the product that the customer purchased.

There are 3 custom options with lengthy names.
Long Brown Corn
Big Orange Cow
Wide Pink Biskit

If the customer has all 3 features, I don't want to crowd up my column with these long names.  So I want to display them as abbreviations with a popup title on mouseover.
LBC, BOC, WPB

Notice at the end of this line, you need that extra blank quote ''.  This is the ELSE part of the IF statement I think.

"title": "= if([$choiceIterator] == 'BOC', 'Big Orange Cow', if([$choiceIterator] == 'LBC', 'Long Brown Corn', if([$choiceIterator] == 'WPB', 'Wide Pink Biskit', '' )"

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "choiceIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[$choiceIterator]",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-white",
        "title": "= if([$choiceIterator] == 'BOC', 'Big Orange Cow', if([$choiceIterator] == 'LBC', 'Long Brown Corn', if([$choiceIterator] == 'WPB', 'Wide Pink Biskit', '' )"
      },
      "style": {
        "width": "28px",
        "height": "16px",
        "text-align": "center",
        "margin": "2px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Span use title as tooltip, so you can set the title as detailed description for each span.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-size": "16px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Water Description",
        "iconName": "Precipitation",
        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if(indexOf(join(@currentField,''),'Water') != -1, 'themeDark', 'neutralLight')"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding": "0 2px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Coffee Description",
        "iconName": "CoffeeScript",
        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if(indexOf(join(@currentField,''),'Coffee') != -1, 'themeDark', 'neutralLight')"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding": "0 2px 0 0"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Wine Description",
        "iconName": "Wines",
        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if(indexOf(join(@currentField,''),'Wine') != -1, 'themeDark', 'neutralLight')"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding": "0 2px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Beer Description",
        "iconName": "BeerMug",
        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if(indexOf(join(@currentField,''),'Beer') != -1, 'themeDark', 'neutralLight')"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding": "0 2px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "\"Juice Description more...\"",
        "iconName": "MusicInCollectionFill",
        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if(indexOf(join(@currentField,''),'\"Juice\"') != -1, 'themeDark', 'neutralLight')"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding": "0 2px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There are many icons you could use.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/icons#icons